# How to delete ripple of an exponential signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise, ripple

I have the following data, which corresponds to a "noisy" exponential shaped signal. 
[image: Graph]
Is there any easy/intuitive way of eliminating the noise/ripple of it to get a clean signal (like filtering)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: use averaging filter https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/examples/averaging-filter.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to throw random ideas around. Please do your own research and once you have a concrete question, update the question.

Comment: xupame un huebo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use median or averaging filters. For example this is from MATLAB's examples:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html 

% Create the signal 
fs = 100;
t = 0:1/fs:1;
x = sin(2*pi*t*3)+0.25*sin(2*pi*t*40);

% Filter 
y = medfilt1(x,10);

%Plot the result 
plot(t,x,t,y);
legend('Original','Filtered');
legend('boxoff');
```

[image]